# Python function freezing during file opening

Tags: python

I have a function that is meant to count the number of times each key in a dictionary occurs in a list of files (`list_of_docs`).

```
def calc(dictionary):
  for token in dictionary:
    count = 0
    for files in list_of_docs:
      current_file = open(files.name, 'r')
      text = current_file.read()
      line = text.split()
      if token in line:
        count +=1
  return count
```

When I call this function, it doesn't stop. When I interrupt the program it indicates that it's stuck on the line `line = text.split()`. (And if I remove that line, it gets stuck on `text = current_doc.read()`.) Not sure why the program isn't stopping?

Answer (score 0):

you are not closing your files, call `current_file.close()` when you are finished reading it.  Alternatively you can wrap the file reading in a `with` statement:

```
with open(current_file, 'r') as f:
    f.read()
    ...
```

Comment: thanks! I tried adding closing the file at the end of the function as well as wrapping the file with a `with` statement. even after updating both, it still appears to be freezing

Comment: Is it always the same file that is freezing?  Is it reading any of the files properly?  If no error is being thrown, then the read function might not be hitting an end of file (EOF).  If it is one file that is causing trouble, I would investigate there.